# Detect JDK installation on computer programatically

Tags: vb.net

This is my code for a function which detects JDK installation on a machine..
The code on execution is giving exceptions which are handled :- [image]

Line No. 164 is  :- `If ndpKey Is Nothing AndAlso ndpKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion") Is Nothing Then`

```
Private Function HAS_JDK() As Boolean
    Try
        Const subkeyjava As String = "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"

        Using ndpKey As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkeyjava)
            If ndpKey Is Nothing AndAlso ndpKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion") Is Nothing Then
                Close()
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End Using

    Catch e As NullReferenceException
        MessageBox.Show("System Error Occured While Checking JDK !! ", "BLA BLA BLA - Error Occured !!")
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString())
        Close()
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: why did you tag this as java, while it's a vb.net task? why would you even want to do this?

Comment: Yeah i know its a vb.net task but i want to know if there is any other solution from java side which i can use ... also its for my application for checking jdk installation..@Stultuske

Comment: if it was a program to check if you have a text editor present, would you have tagged it as a notepad task? so: you are running vb code, meaning no running java vm ... how would java be able to help then?

Comment: you can simply say you don't want that tag i will remove it ... no need to write unnecessary things... i am not here for fighting over your tags.. i am here to learn.. so please take it easy...you need something just ask...don't give a lecture on that...if you know any solution to this you can answer or ignore...its as simple as that...@Stultuske

Comment: if from my last post you don't understand why Java can't help you, you don't know enough of Java to use it. have you debugged your code and checked where that nullreference hits?

Comment: Why are you passing a judgement so early ? -_-
 Have you read the question carefully ?
by the way its "ndpKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion")" if you can't read above in the question..@Stultuske

Comment: The comments _are necessary_ to help clarify the question. Don't get agitated by users who try to help you doing so. Concentrate on improving your question instead.

Comment: i know that and also talking about tags doesn't solve any of my problems @ModusTollens

Comment: @VivekRajAgarwal comments are meant to help you improve your question. Please, to not rant on people trying to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is a bit incorrect. I think what you were after is `OrElse`:

```
If ndpKey Is Nothing OrElse ndpKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion") Is Nothing Then
```

This checks if ***either*** `ndpKey` ***or*** `ndpKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion")` is nothing. If the first check succeeds it won't continue with the second, thus no exception.

Comment: Well i tried your solution , now its telling me that i have not installed jdk but i have jdk installed..so i guess its not working how it is supposed to be..

Comment: @VivekRajAgarwal : That's because the check fails, most likely due to that you use `RegistryView.Registry32`. If the key does not exist in the 32-bit registry then it will of course be `Nothing`. Try fiddling a little with your code to see if you can get it to check the actual registry value, or just skip `RegistryView` and compile your application as `AnyCPU`.

Comment: @VivekRajAgarwal : The code works, but the key you are looking for most likely does not exist in the 32-bit registry. For more info see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It Worked!! On Changing Registry32 to Registry64 Thanks !!

Comment: @VivekRajAgarwal : Glad I could help. Though be aware that if you force it to use the 64-bit view there's no certainty that it will work on a 32-bit system. Best is to set it to `RegistryView.Default` and compile your application as `AnyCPU` instead. That way it will adapt to the current system.

Comment: @VivekRajAgarwal : Or even better, compile it as `AnyCPU` and just change your code to: `Using ndpKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkeyjava)`